# Assign Result Query to Variable

Tags: variables, plsql, while-loop, assign

How do I put a select max query result into an variable and then use it in a while loop in PLSQL? Just an example would be fine.

```
DECLARE
counter NUMBER;
num_max NUMBER:='select max(num_sequencial) from ide_identificacao';

BEGIN
num_max := num_max/1000;
WHILE(counter < num_max)
.....
..
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SELECT ... INTO` clause:

```
DECLARE
counter NUMBER;
num_max NUMBER;

BEGIN
select max(num_sequencial) into num_max from ide_identificacao;

num_max := num_max/1000;
WHILE condition
LOOP
   {...statements...}
END LOOP;
```